# How to focus on a text field when opening an application?

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

*How to focus on a text field when opening an application?*

Swift 4, 
Xcode 10, 
macOS

**ANSWER:**

Thanks to the advice by @Willeke in the comments, I did it this way:

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit
import Foundation
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

class ViewController: NSViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var addDomain: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addSiteField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var removeSite: NSSegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        addDomain.window?.makeFirstResponder(addDomain)

    }
```

Because:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1526750-becomefirstresponder

> Use the **NSWindow makeFirstResponder(_:)** method, not **becomeFirstResponder()** method, to make an object the first responder. **Never invoke this method directly.**

Comment: FYI: you can just paste a code in the post, not an image from your IDE. It's easier for you and for readers of your question. Have a nice coding :)

Comment: Always post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable, and can be copied when answering. Please [edit] your question

Comment: Don't call `becomeFirstResponder`. "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly."

Comment: @Willeke Thanks! Did as you said. Check post please. Now I did the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be not over-riding the **viewDidAppear** that belongs to your **NSViewController**, but you are adding a new function on it's own.

Try using:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    // Though the default implementation does nothing as of now, 
    // it is always safe to have the call to the super function in place, 
    // in case you plan to add sub-classes in between.
    super.viewDidAppear()

    addDomain.window?.makeFirstResponder(addDomain)
}
```

Comment: Don't call `becomeFirstResponder`. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you @Willeke for the pointer! I've updated the answer with the same.

Answer (score -1):

In your `viewController` in `viewDidAppear`

`yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`

**Update:**

`macOS` implementation **requires** using NSWindow `makeFirstResponder`!

Comment: Thanks for attention! Pls check my post. May be something wrong?

Comment: Don't call `becomeFirstResponder`. Please read the documentation.

Comment: @Willeke as per documentation `Call this method when you want to the current object to be the first responder` 

Comment: Please read the macOS version: [becomeFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1526750-becomefirstresponder?language=occ).